# prove a general inequality between radicals

Tags: inequality

I've been trying to work on a proof for this for a few days now, but can't seem to see the answer. It might be trivial but I would be grateful if anyone could let me know their strategy (if not a proof) for this:

$$\sqrt[n]{n!} \lt \sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the logarithm, then this is equivalent to $$\dfrac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\le\dfrac1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\log k.$$ In other wards average of $\log $ of first $n$  positive integers is an increasing function of $n.$ [See this for a graphical interpretation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+log(k)+from+k%3D1+to+k%3Dn)%2Fn)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892518/prove-nth-root-of-n-is-less-than-n1-th-root-of-n1-sqrtnn-lt-sq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise both side to the power of $n$ and then riase it to the power of $n+1$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(n!)^{n+1} < ((n+1)!)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now cancel $(n!)^n$
\begin{eqnarray*}
n! < (n+1)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is obvious, multiply the following inequalities $1 <n+1,2<n+1, \cdots , n<n+1$.

Comment: Ah, of course, simplifying it makes it so obvious! Thank you so much! :)